# Materialize pushpin scrolling jumps

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, materialize, pushpin

So I have a strange issue with scrolling when using the pushpin functionality on a navbar element.

When scrolling down on the page, once the pushpin navbar reaches the top where it becomes fixed, the content on the page jumps upward suddenly.

[Here's a codepen to illustrate what I mean](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgMxam)

If someone can point to what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

---

My initialization of pushpin:

```
$('#navbar').pushpin({
    top: $('#wrapper').offset().top
});
```

General HTML Structure:

```
<div class="intro">
    ...
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav id="navbar">
        ...
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case it helps anyone here's the solution:

Wrap the navbar in a div with a fixed height equal to the navbar. When pushpin changes the navbar from relative to fixed, this changes the way it takes up space in the document. The wrapper div with a set height will conserve that space regardless of the navbar positioning.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav id="navbar">
        ...
    </nav>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#navbar').pushpin({
    top: $('#navbar').offset().top
});
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    //height equal to height of navbar
    height: 64px;
}
```